# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION line 10?

Tags: php, parse-error

What is wrong with my code? I ran the code on my test server and the code worked but when I upload it to my production server I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /hermes/bosweb/web013/b130/ipg.acrsflcom/darayngedbeats/gentest.php on line 10
```

here is my code

```
$old = "http://darayngedbeats1.s3.amazonaws.com    /mp3/CrazyMonsta2.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJXA36ESCLQHCB54Q&Expires=1297279906& Signature=HD36ZQE8yeTIW6JPWKMcciPTiTs%3D"; //enter the key that needs to be converted
$search =  array(":","?","=","&","%");
$replace = array("%3A","%3F","%3D","%26","%25");

function search_replace($s,$r,$sql)
{ $e = '/('.implode('|',array_map('preg_quote', $s)).')/';
  $r = array_combine($s,$r);
  return preg_replace_callback($e, function($v) use ($s,$r) { return $r[$v[1]];  },$sql);
}

echo "<br><br>";
$new = search_replace($search,$replace,$old);
echo $new;

?>
```

Comment: i presume it has to do with the callback function

Comment: line 7                                                          `return preg_replace_callback($e, function($v) use ($s,$r) { return $r[$v[1]];  },$sql);`

Comment: Q: "Which line is line 10?" - A: "line 7 [code]" I lol'd.

Comment: line 7 is 10   return preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The error is likely caused by

```
return preg_replace_callback($e, function($v) use ($s,$r) { return $r[$v[1]];  },$sql);
```

Chances are you're using PHP 5.2 or earlier, which doesn't support closures. You can find out which version of PHP you're using  [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

You'll likely either need to upgrade to PHP 5.3+, or use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), or write a static function and pass it as a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Here's an example of the last option, using a simple class to store the state of `$r`:

```
class My_callback {
  public function __construct($s, $r) {
    $this->s = $s; $this->r = $r;
  } 

  function callback($v) { return $this->r[$v[1]]; }
}

function search_replace($s,$r,$sql) {
  $e = '/('.implode('|',array_map('preg_quote', $s)).')/';
  $r = array_combine($s,$r);
  $c = new My_callback($s, $r);
  return preg_replace_callback($e, array($c, 'callback'), $sql);
}
```

Comment: ok i tryed this `$newfunc = preg_replace_callback($e, create_function($v) use ($s,$r) { return $r[$v[1]]; },$sql);`     now i get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE in /hermes/bosweb/web013/b130/ipg.acrsflcom/darayngedbeats/gentest.php on line 10`

Comment: @user514584: `use` does not exist before PHP 5.3 either. You should have read the documentation @meagar linked to, to see how `create_function` works. Here again: http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php. Unfortunately, you cannot create closures with `create_function` so you have to think about a different way how to access `$r` and `$e` in the callback.

Comment: @user Try just writing a regular function and passing it in as a string.

Comment: doesn't passing a function in as a string use eval()? eval is evil as i recall. It opens too many security holes. Just extract and name it.

Comment: @Scott I'm talking about a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), the same thing you'd pass to `call_user_func`. It has nothing to do with `eval`.

Comment: @Felix I'm new to php i read the documentation and i did not understand it. i didn't make the scrip that I'm trying to use just made modifications to it so can someone give me an example

Comment: ah ok. I misunderstood. yeah that makes perfect sense then.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone getting this error on PHP 5.3+ and especially with a wordpress theme, I would recommend having a look at the formatting of the actual files on the server.

When I encountered this error and viewed the PHP files throwing the error on the server, they had no line breaks and were effectively minified to one line.

For some reason, Filezilla stripped out the line breaks when I uploaded the files and this was what was causing this same error to occur.

By changing the transfer type in Filezilla to Binary (Transfer > Transfer Type > Binary) and re-uploading the wordpress theme, this fixed my issue!

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! Would never have thought to try that but it did indeed fix my 500 errors :)

Comment: Thank you also. Just saved my bacon too!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, this really helped me

Comment: This was a godsend for me.  I was looking for HOURS trying to find the answer and this finally fixed it.  Thank you so much for posting this!!

Answer (score 4):

try extracting your callback function into a separate named function and referring to it by name.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for create_function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

create_function is supported both in php4 and php5

Answer (score 2):

By now this question is mostly obsolete because 5.3 has been around for a long time, but besides the points raised by the other answers, I would like to point out that what you're trying to do can already be done using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$new = strtr($old, array(
  ':' => '%3A',
  '?' => '%3F',
  '=' => '%3D',
  '&' => '%26',
  '%' => '%25',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)
```

In my case, I fixed this error, by adding a semicolon that I've forgotten at the end of a variable declared previously..