# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION line 10 ? help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949573/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-line-10-help)
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

This is the code which cause the error.

```
$remaining = array_filter($allmodels, function ($var) use ($existmodels) {
                return !in_array($var, $existmodels);
        });
```

Logic of the code is(below all are arrays)

```
$remaining = $allmodels - $existmodels;
```

I think My PHP version is outdated in the server. Is it the problem. How can I create a similar code snippet ?

Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/callbacks

Comment: What's your hosting service PHP version? If it's too outdated, you may consider migrating. Starting a new project on 5.2 or older is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of OO programming, so just for the fun:

```
class MyArrayOperations
{
  private $base;

  public function __construct(array $base)
  {
    $this->base = $base;
  }

  public function dif (array $vars ) 
  {
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $this->base as $base )
    if(!in_array($base, $vars))
      $result[] = $base;
    return $result;
  }

$result = (new MyArrayOperations($allmodels))->dif($existmodels);
```

The class can be put in a separate file for reuse, and then just use the oneliner. And, of course the class can be extended with a kind of handy array operations.

**Update**

I realized that the oneliner only will work in php 5.4+, so for older versions use this:

```
$arrayops = new MyArrayOperations($allmodels);
$result = $arrayops->dif($existmodels);
```

Result in [Codepad](http://codepad.org/A3Ut1tgl).

Comment: This just mess up things... not giving -1 anyway

Comment: @yes123 you are right, thanks for pointing that out. I updated and have a example here: http://codepad.org/A3Ut1tgl

Answer (score 3):

Note: of course global isn't a good pratice

```
function fil($var) {
 global $existmodels;
 return !in_array($var, $existmodels);
}

$remaining = array_filter($allmodels, 'fil');
```

Comment: He said he is using old PHP version :(

Answer (score 0):

adding below code to htaccess solved the problem

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```