# PrestaShop Fatal error in module Api: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Tags: prestashop

When I enter prestashop back office and click the modules tab in the top menu it is giving the following error, prestashop version 1.5.3.1

[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module Api:
syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, searched prestashop forums and cannot find a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out it was a problem with Youstice v1.7.2 module

It was causing the API error, what we did in the end was change the name of a folder in the public_html>modules from- "yousticeresolutionsystem" to "yousticeresolutionsystemX"

because it wouldn't allow me to delete the folder to stop the API error.

By using X this in effect deletes the folder stopping the error

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to [version of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949573/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-line-10-help). I had this problem because of unsupported version of module. What I did was [turn on the debug mode](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information/) on PrestaShop which showed me in what module error was happening and then just removed that module from PrestaShop installation diretory, **modules** folder.

If you are using that module, you could backup it, then re-installing it, etc.